# PCA returns less components than was set

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, svm, pca

I want to apply PCA (Principal Component Analysis) on my features vectors and reduce components to 1000, 
one vector has 7440 features, there are in list 200 vectors. W
hen I am training PCA, it returns me only 200 features per vector.

```
print (type(arrVectorFinal))
print len(arrVectorFinal[0])
pca = PCA(n_components=1000)
pca.fit(arrVectorFinal)
X_t_train = pca.transform(arrVectorFinal)
print X_t_train.shape
```

output:

```
<type 'list'>
7440
(200L, 200L)
```

Can someone tell me, what is wrong there?

I tried also `fit_transform`, with no difference... Should I remake somehow list of vectors or? (I tried make it as numpy array).

Comment: Search a bit here (for similar questions). That's a common question and the behaviour is due to the math behind PCA. There is something like ```n_components=min(n_components, n_samples)```.

Comment: So, I can't get more features than number of samples?

Comment: Well, you [don't want to](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/28914/37479).

Comment: Okey, thanks.. I just wanted to improve percentage of my solution, but this doesnt help it  :)